# How to intergrate a bookmark function with has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic blog app with Devise for auth and Im trying to intergrate a bookmark function without using gem with has_many association. How would I do that?

my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
has_many :posts, :through => :bookmarks
end
```

my `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bookmarked_posts, through: :bookmarks, source: :post
end
```

my `Boomark` model:

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1, you have 2 times `has_many :posts` in User model which is not correct, change first to `has_many :own_posts, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: "Post"`

2. create new controller for adding posts to bookmarks and in routes.rb
3. add method

```
def add
  current_user.posts << Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

it is actually could be added in PostsController, but new action anyway must be added in routes.rb. And same for removing posts from bookmarks

Comment: Do I need a rails migration for this?